# Undefined variable: noscript in

Tags: php, variables, joomla, undefined, jumi

I have a php script Jumi installed on Joomla and the error log is full with this error:

> Undefined variable: noscript in
>   /public_html/plugins/system/jumi/jumi.php on line 102

It seems that Jumi is not optimized for PHP 5.4

> line 102>> $content = str_replace('', $noscript . '',
>   $content);
>
> 103>> JResponse::setBody($content);

Can I change this line to make it compatible with PHP 5.4+ ?

Comment: Undefined Variable is just a notice, it shoudln't break your script. If you want to fix it, you need to declare the variable "$noscript" at the start of the page.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Jumi do you have? The last version doesn't have this problem. In any case, `$noscript` is just there to add some `<noscript>` message (if the person doesn't have `JavaScript` enabled), which is not critical for the operation of your website. You can safely add the following before line 102:

```
$noscript = '';
```

If you really need to display a warning for those who don't have JavaScript, then add the following line instead (before line 102):

```
$noscript = '<noscript><strong>JavaScript is currently disabled.</strong>Please enable it for a better experience of Jumi.</noscript>';
```

You can always update to the latest Jumi version to get rid of this problem.

Comment: Thanks. I was using 3.0.4. Updated to 3.0.5 and the error is gone.